# Joomla Content menu name in XML

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm making a content plugin to Joomla, but if I put in the XML the following:

```
<menu>Greatings</menu>
```

It just puts the menu title as "greatings" (lower case) and if i put for example

```
<menu>Greatings A</menu>
```

It puts out "greatings-a".

Any ideia how can i solve this? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by creating a language file and using it.

For example: create a file named [root directory of your site]/administrator/language/en-GB/[your component or module name].sys.ini and write the following string: `GREATINGS_MENU="Greatings"`.
Then, in your XML file, replace `<menu>Greatings</menu>` by `<menu>GREATINGS_MENU</menu>`.